# Error usando tipo de datos enum en componente de Angular

Tags: angular, enum

Estoy aprendiendo Angular y me estoy haciendo una app de tareas. Estoy tratando de usar el tipo `enum` y me da error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was
> expected

El código es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He buscado en google y en la página de stackoverflow en inglés como solucionarlo.

Se puede acceder al proyecto a través de:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fugf4j?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: No lo declares dentro de la clase.

Comment: Vale, gracias @Lobos. Lo he declarado fuera  y también he declarado fuera la interface. Ya no tengo ese error, ahora tengo otro que tiene que ver con el decorador. Pero eso ya no entra en el ámbito de esta pregunta. Por favor escribe una respuesta para que pueda validarla.

Comment: Creo que se debe a que los declaraste entre el decorador y la clase.  Deben ir antes del decorador.

Comment: @Lobos, efectivamente ya no tengo el error en el decorador. Me pregunto por qué pasa esto.

Comment: Porque el decorador pertenece a la clase que se quiere modificar. Por eso no puede ir nada entre el decorador y la clase.